# How to check if a value in one column is in other column when the queried column have many values?

Tags: python, pandas

**Question**

How to check if a value in one column is in other column when the queried column have many values?

**The minimal reproducible example**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'patient': ['patient1', 'patient1', 'patient1','patient2', 'patient2', 'patient3','patient3','patient4'], 
                   'gene':['TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR','TYR'],
                   'variant': ['buu', 'luu', 'stm','lol', 'bla', 'buu', 'lol','buu'],
                    'genotype': ['buu,luu,hola', 'gulu,melon', 'melon,stm','melon,buu,lol', 'bla', 'het', 'het','het']})

print(df1)

    patient gene variant       genotype
0  patient1  TYR     buu   buu,luu,hola
1  patient1  TYR     luu     gulu,melon
2  patient1  TYR     stm      melon,stm
3  patient2  TYR     lol  melon,buu,lol
4  patient2  TYR     bla            bla
5  patient3  TYR     buu            het
6  patient3  TYR     lol            het
7  patient4  TYR     buu            het
```

**What I have tried**

```
df1.variant.isin(df1.genotype)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: variant, dtype: bool
```

This does not work. The expected  result would be:

```
0    True
1    False
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: variant, dtype: bool
```

I don't know how many different values the column genotype has. This vary a lot from 1 to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.apply` + `str.split`:

```py
print(df1.apply(lambda x: x['variant'] in x['genotype'].split(','), axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

With a *listcomp* :

```
[var in gen for var,gen in zip(df1["variant"], df1["genotype"])]
```

Output :

```
# with the Series constructor pd.Series(...)

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a simple `function` and use `apply` to iterate it through all rows.

```
def check_variant(df):
    
    return True if df['genotype'].find(df['variant']) != -1 else False
```

and Trigger:

```
df1.apply(check_variant, axis=1)
```

Results:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
```

7    False